# Arabic Language conversion php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, arabic

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
mysql_query("update `mudasser`
             set `name`='$name',
                `ar_name`='$ar_name',
                `address`='$address',
                `type`='$type',
                `telephone`='$telephone',
                `date_added`='$date',
                `image`='$file'
            where `id`='$id'"
```

when i echo the query this is the result

```
update `mudasser` set `name`='Boknan', `ar_name`='بوكنان', `address`='E2', `type`='Abaya Galabia', `telephone`='2535338', `date_added`='2015-06-01 08:54:11', `image`='Boknan.jpg' where `id`='128'
```

You can see the arabic name appearing correct 
but in the database the arabic name is somehow like this `???????`

If i run this query directly in mysql, it runs perfect and it is also reading correct arabic in php page.

For reference i am using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">` in php and also using utf-8 in db.

I have searched the net and Stackoverflow but i cant find any answer.

Comment: Your current character encoding is probably set incorrectly.

Comment: Uhhhmmm @leggendario I think you edited out an important part of the question... (the question marks)

Comment: @sameed when you say "somehow like this" were those question marks meant to be there? As in, that is what you see?

Comment: the code is working perfect otherwise, the problem is just with arabic. if i write this query in mysql it runs perfectly fine.
but through PHP its not entering the correct arabic value

Comment: yes those were the question marks that meant to b there, part of question

Comment: @Leggendario no worries. It was easy to miss :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before executing the update query.

either

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

or

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
```

**utf8mb4** is preferred. Which was introduced in MySQL 5.3.3, use it if possible.

[read more about difference in UTF8 and UTF8mb4 and how to switch to mb4](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4)

Comment: that is perfect.it has solved the query.
million thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table's CHARSET and COLLATE Properties.

For columns check "Encoding" and "Collation" properties.

CHARSET/Encoding should be utf8
Collate/Collation should be utf8_bin

Comment: its mentioned they are encoded and collated same as u suggested

Answer (score 0):

1. ar_name need to be a nvarchar type
2. Put N in front of the arabic characters - N'بوكنان'

Comment: The N is optional in MySQL.